# Como hago para que el bucle while salga al cancelar un prompt

Tags: javascript

hola tengo este codigo :

```
const calculatorPro = () => {
let numberList = [];
let newNumber;
let loopBreak = true;

while(loopBreak === true){
  if(newNumber !== null){
    newNumber = parseFloat(prompt('Enter a number or press cancel to stop.'));
    parseInt(newNumber);
    numberList.push(newNumber);
    
    if(newNumber === '' || isNaN(newNumber)){
    alert('Is not a number, please enter a number.')
}}else{
loopBreak = false;}}}
```

Quiero que cuando el usuario presione cancelar en el prompt salga del bucle al cambiar el booleano a false, pero al presionar cancelar me salta el alert. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La función `prompt` devuelve `null` cuando presionan cancelar. Por la tanto, verifica si lo es, y haz que se corte el ciclo.

```js
let numberList = [];
let newNumber;

while(true){
   input = prompt('Enter a number or press cancel to stop.')
   if(input == null)
        break

   newNumber = parseFloat(input);

   if(newNumber == "" || isNaN(newNumber))
       alert("It's not a number, please enter a number.")
   else
       numberList.push(newNumber)
    
}
```

Comment: [LOG]: [25, NaN, NaN, NaN] si se ingresa un valor no desado igual lo agrega al array

Comment: El pedía cómo hacer que salga del bucle no que no agregue `NaN`s. Arreglado.